# How to align the text view in the TableLayout.LayoutParams to the parent right of the table column?

Tags: android

```
lblDate = new TextView(
PromotionProfile.this);
lblDate.setText(submitDate);
lblDate.setTextSize(16);
lblDate.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
lblDate.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 0);

lblID = new TextView(PromotionProfile.this);
lblID.setText("ID " + loginID);
lblID.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
lblID.setTextSize(16);
lblID.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
lblID.setPadding(0, 5, 10, 5);

lbl_brand = new TextView(
PromotionProfile.this);
lbl_brand.setText(merchantName);
lbl_brand.setTextSize(16);
lbl_brand.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
lbl_brand.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 0);

lbl_pts = new TextView(
PromotionProfile.this);
lbl_pts.setText(points + " Points");
lbl_pts.setTextSize(16);
lbl_pts.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
lbl_pts.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
lbl_pts.setPadding(0, 5, 10, 5);

row1 = new TableRow(PromotionProfile.this);
row2 = new TableRow(PromotionProfile.this);

row1.addView(lblDate);
row1.addView(lblID);
row2.addView(lbl_brand);
row2.addView(lbl_pts);
tbPoints.addView(row1);
tbPoints.addView(row2);
```

> I want to make the lblID and the lbl_pts to be aligned to the right in
>   the table column. I had tried RelativeLayout.LayoutParams methods, But still can't work out..
>   May I know the solution? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I settled it myself by put in this section of codes :)

lblDate.setLayoutParams( new TableRow.LayoutParams( 0, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 5 ) ); lblID.setLayoutParams( new TableRow.LayoutParams( 0, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 5 ) ); lbl_brand.setLayoutParams( new TableRow.LayoutParams( 0, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 5 ) ); lbl_pts.setLayoutParams( new TableRow.LayoutParams( 0, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 5 ) );